# From Object Array to FormData

Tags: javascript, jquery, multipartform-data

I have an object with data and a file, I need to convert the whole thing into formData, but when I append everything to the formData, the file comes as empty.

Eventually, on the back end, when I try to do `req.files` it comes as an empty array.

Here's an image of the object I have:
[image]

After that, I try to append it to formData: here's the example of my code my code:

```
let data = getInfo();

for (let p of data) {
    var postData = JSON.stringify(p);
    var formData = new FormData();
    formData.append( "data", postData );
    console.log(formData.get("data"));  <--- This has file as empty.
}
```

This is the response of the console.log

```
{"price_floor":1000000,"cost":1100000,"templateId":"1","locationId":"21","file":{}}
```

Why is file not getting attached when I append it to the formData?

Comment: You can't put a file in JSON.

Answer (score 0):

**It is not possible to directly convert a [File](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/File) object into JSON using `JSON.stringify`**

**You can try to use custom replacer**

---

```js
function stringify(obj) {
    const replacer = [];
    for (const key in obj) {
        replacer.push(key);
    }
    return JSON.stringify(obj, replacer);
}

$("#file").change(function(){
  const json = stringify($(this)[0].files[0]);
  console.log(json);
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="wrap">
  <div>
    <form id="form">
      <label for="lname">File:</label><br>
      <input type="file" id="file" name="file"><br><br>
    </form>
  </div>
</div>
```

**But my personal habit is to get `FormData` like this**

---

```js
$("#file").change(function(){
  const data = Object.fromEntries(new FormData(form).entries());
  console.log(data);
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="wrap">
  <div>
    <form id="form">
      <label for="name">Name:</label><br>
      <input type="text" id="name" name="name"><br>
      <label for="lname">File:</label><br>
      <input type="file" id="file" name="file"><br><br>
    </form>
  </div>
</div>
```